# Preciso q a clausula GROUP BY seja lida depois da HAVING

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Meu problema é o seguinte, a distancia é a informação crucial para minha pesquisa, e eu preciso usar também o GROUP by para não aparecer vários produtos iguais!

Então como o group by vem antes do having, SE a primeira informação do "p.id" retornada for em alguma distancia maior que 5(mesmo existindo esse produto em outros estabelecimento ele não irá retornar para mim) pq o group by ordenou pela primeira aparição do p.id e o having veio depois e tirou vários estabelecimento com a distância >5, portanto tirando vários produtos que apareceria,

Alguém já passou por algo parecido  e tem alguma solução?

Tenho  o seguinte SQL do mysql:

```
SELECT p.id, p.link_imagem, p.nome produto, p.descricao, p.volume, p.volume_tipo, t.tipo, e.nome,
                            ROUND((6371 * acos(
                                    cos(radians(end.latitude)) *
                                    cos(radians(e.latitude)) *
                                    cos(radians(end.longitude) - radians(e.longitude)) +
                                    sin(radians(end.latitude)) *
                                    sin(radians(e.latitude))
                                )),1) AS distancia
                          FROM produtos as p
                INNER JOIN enderecos as end on(end.usuarioid = '94' and end.status = '1')               
                INNER JOIN cardapios as c on(c.produtoid = p.id)
                INNER JOIN estabelecimentos as e on(e.id = c.estabelecimentoid)
                INNER JOIN tipos as t on(t.id = p.tipoid)
                WHERE p.nome like '%coca%' 
                GROUP BY p.id
                HAVING distancia <= 5 ORDER BY distancia
```

Comment: O HAVING sempre vem depois do GROUP, é um filtro sobre valores agregados como SUM(), COUNT(), que você nem está usando. Sem algumas linhas das tabelas não tem como testar, mas acho que você não deveria usar o GROUP BY e o HAVING deveria ser substituido por WHERE. O INNER JOIN com os endereços é um produto cartesiano, então você obviamente vai ter múltiplas linhas com o mesmo produto porque vc esta medindo a distância de cada produto contra uma lista de endereços.

Comment: Você pode fazer `select t.* from (sua_consulta_sem_group_by_sem_having) as t where t.distancia <= 5 group by t.id order by t.distancia`, lembrando que isso vai reduzir o desempenho da consulta, que pode ser imperceptível ou não.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você deseja realizar um comando antes do outro no mesmo **SELECT** eu recomendaria utilizar o conceito de **SUBSELECT**:

```
--Segundo SELECT
SELECT DISTINCT resultado.*
FROM (
      --Primeiro SELECT
      SELECT p.id, p.link_imagem, p.nome produto, p.descricao, p.volume, 
      p.volume_tipo, t.tipo, e.nome,
      ROUND((6371 * acos(
              cos(radians(end.latitude)) *
              cos(radians(e.latitude)) *
              cos(radians(end.longitude) - radians(e.longitude)) +
              sin(radians(end.latitude)) *
              sin(radians(e.latitude))
          )),1) AS distancia
      FROM produtos as p
      INNER JOIN enderecos as end on(end.usuarioid = '94' and end.status = '1')               
      INNER JOIN cardapios as c on(c.produtoid = p.id)
      INNER JOIN estabelecimentos as e on(e.id = c.estabelecimentoid)
      INNER JOIN tipos as t on(t.id = p.tipoid)
      WHERE p.nome like '%coca%' 
      --Primeiro o HAVING
      HAVING distancia <= 5 ORDER BY distancia  
      ) resultado
--Segundo o Group BY
GROUP BY resultado.id
```

Primeiro é executado o primeiro **SELECT** com o **HAVING**, depois é executado um **SELECT** com o **GROUP BY**, também inclui o **DISTINCT** para garantir a remoção dos dados duplicados.

Comment: Meu, muito obrigado, funcionou sim, isso me deu uma dor de cabeça enorme! Você é foda!